# See if length between two equal numbers in deque is even

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `deque<int>` and I want to find if the number of `int`s between two equal numbers is even. For example:`7,13,4,6,4,13,8,10` should be false and `1,3,5,3,4,8,7,9,6,5,7` should be true. I think my program is correct, but or some reason it outputs true for both cases. Any ideas why? PS: I'm not good with iterators.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
  bool isJoined ( deque<int>::iterator begin, deque<int>::iterator end )
 {
    for(auto i = begin ; i < end ;i++)
      for(auto j=i+1;j<end;j++)
        if(*i == *j && (j-i)%2 == 0)
          return true;    

   return false;
 }
int main()
{    
   deque<int> test = {1,3,5,3,4,8,7,9,6,5,7};   
   deque<int> test2 = {7,13,4,6,4,13,8,10};
   cout<<isJoined(test.begin(),test.end())<<endl;
   cout<<isJoined(test2.begin(),test2.end())<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You can access deques with `[]` notation

Comment: between any two equal ? what is answer for 2 1 2 3 4 5 3 ?

Comment: @migdal The answer is true. Between the two `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error here:

```
if(*i == *j && (j-i)%2 == 0)
```

You want to count the number of numbers strictly between the iterators... that is for `[1, 2, 3, 1]` you want `2`, but the difference between the iterators will give you `3`. Thus, you want:

```
if (*i == *j && (j-i+1)%2 == 0)
```

or

```
if (*i == *j && (j-i)%2 == 1)
```

Also you might find it easier to just use the index operator and avoid iterators altogether:

```
bool isJoined(const deque<int>& deq)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < deq.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < deq.size(); ++j) {
            if (deq[i] == deq[j] && (j-i)%2 == 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That way also lets you straddle the inner loop:

```
for (size_t j = i+1; j < deq.size(); j += 2) {
    // already enforcing an even number of numbers in bewteen
    if (deq[i] == deq[j]) return true; 
}
```